# Simple self-made encrypter

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

The following code:

```
import random

def keygen():
    l = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]|\:;?/~`"" ')
    random.shuffle(l)
    return l

def encrypt(x):
    key = keygen() #or a static key for consistency
    y = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]|\:;?/~`"" ')
    z = dict(zip(y, key))
    l = []
    for match in list(x):
        l.append(match.replace(match, z[match]))
    print('key: '+ ''.join(key))
    print('content: '+ ''.join(l))

def decrypt(key, x):
    key = list(key)
    y = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]|\:;?/~`"" ')
    z = dict(zip(key, y))
    l = []
    for match in list(x):
        l.append(match.replace(match, z[match]))
    print(''.join(l))
```

is just a simple self made encrypter that I made for fun, and works like so:

```
>>> encrypt('hello world how are you')
key: ^lps1|dv)({t&hk#w;=@!6bjrx$4 \[m~"q*i+:-a73?u/5zf%gc9}yn"8_oe]`2
content: v1ttk2bk;ts2vkb2^;12rk!
>>> decrypt('^lps1|dv)({t&hk#w;=@!6bjrx$4 \[m~"q*i+:-a73?u/5zf%gc9}yn"8_oe]`2', 'v1ttk2bk;ts2vkb2^;12rk!')
hello world how are you
>>>
```

This works pretty well, but I did see one time where there was a single letter that was misplaced. This could have just been due to me not copy/pasting the key in right for decoding, but I am not so sure. Basically does this code look sound? And are there any other methods of doing something like this in a more elegant way?

Comment: That has a name and it is [_Substitution cipher_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get out of the habit of `print`ing results instead of `return`ing them; if you `return` the function is reusable. Remember that you can return multiple values with:

```
    return ''.join(key), ''.join(l)
```

I would personally suggest returning a string directly from `keygen`.

You don't need to convert `y` to a `list`, and probably should name it better (eg. `ascii`). It would be better as a global constant.

`encrypt` and `decrypt` can be unified by making `key` optional and reversing the arguments when decrypting relative to encrypting; it's symmetric after all.

```
import random

ASCII = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]|\:;?/~`"" '

def keygen():
    l = list(ASCII)
    random.shuffle(l)
    return ''.join(l)

def cipher(x, key=None, backwards=False):
    if key is None:
        key = keygen()

    z = dict(zip(key, ASCII) if backwards else zip(ASCII, key))

    l = []
    for match in list(x):
        l.append(match.replace(match, z[match]))

    return key, ''.join(l)
```

Since `keygen` is so easy to call as

```
encrypt(x, keygen())
```

I wouldn't make `key` have a default. This gives the simpler:

```
import random

ASCII = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]|\:;?/~`"" '

def keygen():
    l = list(ASCII)
    random.shuffle(l)
    return ''.join(l)

def cipher(x, key, backwards=False):
    z = dict(zip(key, ASCII) if backwards else zip(ASCII, key))

    l = []
    for match in list(x):
        l.append(match.replace(match, z[match]))

    return key, ''.join(l)
```

Looking at

```
    l = []
    for match in list(x):
        l.append(match.replace(match, z[match]))
```

we have a lot of inefficiencies. You should just do

```
    for match in x:
```

and then

```
        l.append(z[match])
```

since the `replace` is a no-op.

This can be a list comprehension:

```
    l = [z[match] for match in x]
```

This is now just

```
import random

ASCII = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]|\:;?/~`"" '

def keygen():
    l = list(ASCII)
    random.shuffle(l)
    return ''.join(l)

def cipher(x, key, backwards=False):
    z = dict(zip(key, ASCII) if backwards else zip(ASCII, key))

    l = [z[match] for match in x]
    return ''.join(l)
```

You can then replace some of the challenge with `str.translate` and `str.maketrans`:

```
import random

ASCII = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]|\:;?/~`"" '

def keygen():
    l = list(ASCII)
    random.shuffle(l)
    return ''.join(l)

def cipher(x, key, backwards=False, base_chars=ASCII):
    if backwards:
        base_chars, key = key, base_chars

    return x.translate(str.maketrans(base_chars, key))
```

#### The bug

There is a duplicate character in `ASCII`. This can, and does, break things

```
                                                                      ↓↓
ASCII = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789!@#$%^&*()_-+={}[]|\:;?/~`"" '
                                                                      ↑↑
```

Personally, your best best is just to use `string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + string.punctuation`, despite it being slightly different to the above. This gives

```
import random
import string

ASCII = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits + string.punctuation

def keygen():
    l = list(ASCII)
    random.shuffle(l)
    return ''.join(l)

def cipher(x, key, backwards=False, base_chars=ASCII):
    if backwards:
        base_chars, key = key, base_chars

    return x.translate(str.maketrans(base_chars, key))
```

Of course, [don't roll your own crypto](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own).

Comment: kudos for spotting the repeat ". I was noticing that occasionally things were not decoding properly.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the following link for how XOR Ciphers work.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher

More specifically check the following function:

```
def xor_strings(s,t):
    """xor two strings together"""
    return "".join(chr(ord(a)^ord(b)) for a,b in zip(s,t))
```

If you're interested in more generally accepted encryption techniques check out:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524994/encrypt-decrypt-using-pycrypto-aes-256

But yea it's almost always better just to use AES since it's been tried and tested.

Comment: This is not a review of the code in question, and the advice is not relevant to the algorithm.